# ERC-20 Data Dumps Missing Some Tokens?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, erc20

I've been recently working on a project which involves processing some ERC-20 transactions data which I have downloaded from Blockchair.com through this link: https://gz.blockchair.com/ethereum/erc-20/transactions/

Once I've finished inserting all the data dumps I needed, I ran some queries and to my surprise, some currencies that are available on Blockchair.com were not available in the dumps they provided despite belonging to ERC-20. For instance, [Mute.io](https://explorer.bitquery.io/ethereum/token/0xa49d7499271ae71cd8ab9ac515e6694c755d400c) and Depo.

I'm quite new to blockchain so I'm not really sure if I'm missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: While this is a valid question, this is a support question for Blockchair and not a question the general programming community can answer.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I've reached out to them but unfortunately have not got an explanation. Mute.io is available on their own website here https://blockchair.com/ethereum/erc-20/token/0xa49d7499271ae71cd8ab9ac515e6694c755d400c
hence I'm confused why it's missing in the data dumps I've downloaded.

Comment: Sorry, we cannot help on what appears to be a business problem of poorly run business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the tokens weren't missing, but addresses were trimmed. In my case I just had to remove `0x` from the address string and my issue was solved.